# Enforce Site-Wide Alternate Text Validation On General Link Fields

Tags: templates, validation, links, accessibility

I am working on Sitecore version 9.1. When attempting to insert a link using the general link field, the user is prompted to enter the following information:

[image]

In an effort to enforce accessibility on the site, we would like the content authors to be prompted with a validation error message if they attempt to create a link without supplying a title attribute. This title text is supplied through the `Alternate Text` field in the image above. Based on what I've seen from posts like the following:

https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/02/22/add-telephone-link-to-the-general-link-field-type-in-sitecore/

I have created a link text validator that works just fine if I apply it to an individual link field:

```
using Sitecore.Data.Validators;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class LinkAltTextValidator : StandardValidator
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Link alt text validator"; }
        }

        public LinkAltTextValidator() {}

        public LinkAltTextValidator(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

        protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
        {
            Field field = this.GetField();
            if (field == null)
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;

            string str1 = this.ControlValidationValue;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || string.Compare(str1, "<link>", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;

            XmlValue xmlValue = new XmlValue(str1, "link");
            string attribute = xmlValue.GetAttribute("title");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlValue.GetAttribute("title")))
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;

            this.Text = this.GetText("Alternate text is missing in the link field \"{0}\".", field.DisplayName);
            // return the failed result value defined in the parameters for this validator; if no Result parameter
            // is defined, the default value FatalError will be used
            return this.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.CriticalError);
        }

        protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
        {
            return this.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that I would like to apply this validator to every link on the site. Right now, to apply the validator (say for all Button templates on the site) I have to go to the individual link field in a template and select the validator in the `Validation Rules` section of the standard fields list. I've tried applying the validator to the `General Link` and `Link` field types validators as follows but that did not seem to prompt the validator to run on save for those fields:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can get this validator to be applied site-wide? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out! Most of the links I was trying to apply this validator to were of type `General Link with Search`. For a field type validator to run, evidently you need to have a `Field Type Validation Rules` template in the `Field Types` folder that exactly matches the name of the field you're trying to validate. The path to this field types folder is as follows:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types`

My initial issue was I was trying to apply my validator to the `General Link` template found in this folder which did not match the type name of the majority of the links on my site. I went back and found a few examples of General Link fields on the site and these had been running the validator correctly the entire time. Here is an example of my new setup:

[image]

Note that in order to get this to work I had to add the `General Link with Search` template and set the validator I wanted to apply in the `Validation Rules` section of the standard fields. Hope this helps someone else out!